# I would like to increment the build revision version for every build in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to increment the build revision version for every new successful build.

I mentioned the version number in `SharedAssemblyInfo` class as

```
 [assembly: AssemblyVersion("18.12.0.*")]
```

I am facing the versioning issue because of the below scenario.

If you the put “*” at the 4th box in the above step, the version will be generated as `1.0.0.Y` where `Y` is the number of seconds from midnight. This may cause a versioning issue. For example,  when the last version was build in the afternoon yesterday (e.g. Y=15000, the version is 1.0.0.15000) and the new version is built today morning (Y=8000, the version number will be 1.0.0.8000),  then the new version number is smaller than the old version.

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Just FIY, what you're trying to automatically increment isn't the build version, but actually the revision version. See the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#remarks) for reference

Comment: Version is in format: <major version>.<minor version>.<build number>.<revision>, you are expected to use `"18.12.*"` if you wan't that *"default build number increments daily"* ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute)).

Comment: I do agree with you, but I need increment by one